# Ubuntu 11.04 and ATI Catalyst 11.5 graphics artifacts

Tags: 11.04, ati, graphics, fglrx, visual-artifacts

I have installed ATI Catalyst 11.5 driver (fglrx) on my laptop with Ubuntu 11.04 and switchable-graphics technology (ATI Mobility Radeon HD5470). Everything seems ok, `fglrxinfo` shows my discrete video card working, `glxgears` shows nearly 2000fps, Unity works, no graphical problems etc. But when i try to play games, i.e. Heroes Of Newerth (it has native linux client), my display are all full of graphical blinking artifacts, I think you what I am talking about.

How can I fix this?

**Added later:**
Also I noticed, that when I playing video online via flash player it works good, but when I expand it to full screen, it begins to flash and other annoying artifacts

**Added a bit later:**
The problem is any application(video, game, etc.) in Fullscreen mode.  I tried to check off "Full Screen Mode" in game, and there were no artifacts at all, but have some periodic lags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I completely reinstall Ubuntu 11.04, and installed from scratch Catalyst 11.7, every bug disappered. So now I enjoy gaming, video and other things in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm Have had a few problems with ATI's driver. Have you attempted to try to use the control centre that comes with ATI driver

You used to be able to access it from the terminal:

DISPLAY=:0 amdcccle

You could also perhaps have a look at the answers that they have on the faq on the ATI catalyst Linux site here:

[ATI Linux site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

Comment: I tried every option in `amdcccle`, but there are only 3d effects improvements options, like Anti-aliasing, anisotropic filter etc. Nothin about fullscreen. So, nothing helped. And i didn't find anything on that site, about fullscreen problems in games